# JavaScript notebook

Tags: javascript, note-taking, node.js

I want a notebook software for JavaScript or node.js that supports Markdown and running code in itself.
Similar to what Jupyter Notebook does for Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it, but a quick Google search gave [JS Notebook](https://jbook.qiushiyan.dev/) which supports both Markdown documentation and JavaScript:

> ## Welcome to javascript-notebook
>
> This is an interactive coding environment for JavaScript and Typescript, similar to Jupyter Notebook.
> There are two types of cells
>
> - a text cell, the cell you are reading right now. You can click to edit this cell via markdown syntax, and the content will automatically render to HTML once you click outside the cell.
> - a code cell, where you may input some js or ts code for the browser to execute.